# How can I apply typescript to styled component, so that I can see recommended props on component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Hello Devs! I'm trying to adapt to typescript.

As I get accustomed to typescript it's a bit inconvenient that I cannot see recommended props on a styled component.

For example,

```js
import {TitleInput} from 'react-native';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const MyStyledInput = styled(TextInput)``;

...

const ExComponent = () => {
  return (
    <TextInput/> // This shows prop recommendations. (ex) onChange, onChangeText, etc)
    <MyStyledInput/> // This doesn't. (no recommendations are shown.)
  )
}
```

I guess I can provide type by using **`React.Element<???>`**, just like this:

```js
const MyStyledInput: React.Element<???> = styled(TextInput)``;
```

But I'm not sure about

1. if this approach would work and,
2. if this would work then what types should I provide in the `<???>`.

**How can I provide type to styled component, so that I can get prop recommendations?**

---

**Tried these approaches so far**

1. Providing type at the end of callback

```js
import {TextInput, TextInputProps, TextInputComponent, } from 'react-native';
const MyStyledInput = styled(TextInput)<TextInput>``; // Not working
const MyStyledInput = styled(TextInput)<TextInputProps>``; // Not working
const MyStyledInput = styled(TextInput)<TextInputComponent>``; // Not working
```

---

**What I've found**

1. `TextInputProps` is the target type that I'm seeking to implement, which has props that are listed on the [react-native official site](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput.html#props)

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript)? Syntax looks to be more like `styled(TextInput)<???>``;`

Comment: It's for inner props, which we can use in the `color: {(props) => props.acive ? 'yellow' : 'red'}`!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
React.FC is a type for Functional component. We can provide prop type to React.FC just like this: React.FC

```js
const MyStyledTextInput: React.FC<TextInputProps> = styled(TextInput)``;
// Now you can see recommendations for TextInputProps.
```